# Posting Form Data with python, HTTP/1.1 and custom user agent

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, httplib

I have a form that I need to post data to, however it must have a specific user agent string and HTTP/1.1 headers, (not just host it explicitly looks for HTTP/1.1 in the POST string.)

I've attempted this so far as follow:

```
class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = "The User Agent String"

urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()

def send_data(url, kv)
    params = urllib.urlencode(kv)
    f = urllib.urlopen(url, params)
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
```

However, this submits via HTTP/1.0 with a Host: header.  Looking at the source to urllib (and urllib2) It looks like the codepaths all instantiate a HTTPLib HTTP Class object which is marked as a compatible class from 1.5...  Is there an easy way to have urllib/URLOpener use HTTPConnection instead of HTTP?  Or is there another solution I'm missing to have the proper headers that I need?

Answer (score 2):

cURL allows for a greater deal of customization -- it's available for Python via the pycurl package. Perhaps something like the following would serve your needs:

```
import pycurl
import StringIO

response = StringIO.StringIO()
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTP_VERSION, pycurl.CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1)
curl.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 [...]')

curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, response.write)
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://path.to/form')
curl.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1) 
curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, 'form input') 

curl.perform()
print response.getvalue()
```

There's a [list of configurable options](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) on the cURL website, most of which are accessible in pycurl in the manner shown above (pycurl.OPTION_NAME).